# How to make background of modal popup darker and non transparent in unity?

Tags: unity-game-engine, unity-container

I have a modal pop up in which I show a list of stories title and a button to  open a browser that points the link of the stories, but the pop up is now transparent I want the background to appear darker

[image: My Modal pop up]

Need to modify my modal pop up without a transparent background or make the background color darker, or how can I change the GUI modals opaque or can I set opaque value for this GUI?

please check my modal pop up code here:

```
using UnityEngine;
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic; 
using System.Collections.ObjectModel; 
// example:
// HFTDialog.MessageBox("error", "Sorry but you're S.O.L", () => { Application.Quit() });

public class HFTDialog : MonoBehaviour {
    Rect m_windowRect;
    Action m_action;
    string m_title;
    string m_msg;
    string[] m_myNewsTitleColl;
    string[] m_myColl;
    GUIStyle labelStyle, labelStyleShadow, buttonStyle, sliderStyle, sliderThumbStyle;
    // The position on of the scrolling viewport
    public Vector2 scrollPosition = Vector2.zero;
   private GUIStyle guiStyle; //create a new variable

    static public void MessageBox(string[] myNewsTitleColl, string[] myColl,string title, string msg, Action action)
    {
        GameObject go = new GameObject("HFTDialog");
        HFTDialog dlg = go.AddComponent<HFTDialog>();
        dlg.Init(myNewsTitleColl,myColl,title, msg, action);
    }

    static public void CloseMessageBox(GameObject go)
    {
       Destroy(go.gameObject);
    }

    void Init( string[] myNewsTitleColl,string[] myColl,string title, string msg, Action action)
    {
        m_title = title;
        m_msg = msg;
        m_action = action;
        m_myColl=myColl;
        m_myNewsTitleColl=myNewsTitleColl;
    }

    void OnGUI()
    {
        const int maxWidth  = 640;
        const int maxHeight = 480;//480;
        int width = Mathf.Min(maxWidth, Screen.width - 20);
        int height = Mathf.Min(maxHeight, Screen.height - 20);
        m_windowRect = new Rect(
            (Screen.width - width) / 2,
            (Screen.height - height) / 2,
            width,
            height);
        GUI.color    = Color.white;
        GUI.backgroundColor = Color.yellow;

       m_windowRect   = GUI.Window(0, m_windowRect, WindowFunc, m_title);


    }

    void WindowFunc(int windowID)
    {
        const int border = 10;
        const int width = 50;
        const int height = 25;
        const int spacing = 10;


        guiStyle = new GUIStyle();
        //guiStyle.fontSize = 14; //change the font size
        guiStyle.fontStyle = FontStyle.Bold;
        guiStyle.normal.textColor = Color.white;

        int myNewsTitlePositionY=border + spacing;//Initial position 
        if(m_myNewsTitleColl.Length==0){
           Rect l = new Rect(border, myNewsTitlePositionY,m_windowRect.width - border * 2,m_windowRect.height - border * 2 - height - spacing);
           GUI.Label(l, "Currently No News Available ,Please try later..",guiStyle);//This is the news title label
        }
       else{
    for(var i = 0; i < m_myNewsTitleColl.Length; i++)
    {
           var NewsTitle = m_myNewsTitleColl[i];
           Rect l = new Rect(border, myNewsTitlePositionY,m_windowRect.width - border * 2,m_windowRect.height - border * 2 - height - spacing);
           GUI.Label(l, NewsTitle,guiStyle);//This is the news title label
           myNewsTitlePositionY=myNewsTitlePositionY+33;//next y position of the news title label
        }
       }
    int myY=-15;
    for(var i = 0; i < m_myColl.Length; i++)
    {
         var item = m_myColl[i];
         // work with link item here to make a button
         myY=myY+33; //Y position  of button
             Rect btn = new Rect(550,myY,  width+25,  height);    
         //Rect btn = new Rect(510,myY,  width+25,  height);  //when scroll enable -  
         if (GUI.Button(btn, "Open Link"))
            {
                //open browser pointing the url
             Application.OpenURL(item);
            }
         Debug.Log ("from string array value is :"+item);
    }
    //End Scrollview
  // GUI.EndScrollView();
       Rect b = new Rect(
            m_windowRect.width - width - border,
            m_windowRect.height - height - border,
            width,
            height);
        if (GUI.Button(b, "close"))
        {
            Destroy(this.gameObject);
          //  m_action();
        }


    }
}
```

Comment: You're using Unity 2019. This means you are definitely post Unity 4.6. Use [UGUI](https://docs.unity3d.com/2019.1/Documentation/Manual/UISystem.html) not [IMGUI](https://docs.unity3d.com/2019.1/Documentation/Manual/gui-Basics.html). imgui (Immediate UI) is hard to debug, inflexible, and forces all of your static UI into code that must be executed every frame in order to be visible. UGUI uses game objects in the scene view, which is faster, easier to use, and much more customizable. IMGUI's sole remaining usage is for editor scripting.